# Secured WebSocket does not work in Chrome58

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, websocket

I have upgraded my Chrome to 58 and found the secured WebSocket isn't working any more, the console shows (WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:1234/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE), I know Google has deprecated the SHA1 certificate, so created a new self-signed certificate with SHA256, but it still doesn't work, so is the self-signed cert not allowed in this scenario? (I'm using "new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:1234")")

Comment: "isn't working any more" isn't really informative.

Comment: Use the developer tools and look at the console for messages which indicate a problem. Add these to your question if you don't understand them.

Comment: @gre_gor  I've updated the question

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I've updated the question

Comment: @Edgar: try to access https://127.0.0.1:1234/ which should result in the same error, but in the browser window. From there you get the option to show more details and maybe also to bypass the warning. Once you successfully bypassed it for this site it should work for wss:// too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, that makes the error disappeared, however, I'm still wondering why this happens, in previous Chrome, like 57, it worked properly.

Comment: @Edgar: This usually happens if the certificate has changed or if some essential browser settings were reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the certificate should have a subjectAltName with "IP = 127.0.0.1" for my cert to work in Chrome58, not sure if it's a Chrome bug or new requirement

Comment: Confirmed.  `subjectAltName` of `localhost` will work just fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Please see @Edgar's answer.  `subjectAltName` seems to have become a requirement for self-signed certificates since Chrome 58.

It appears the OP has [asked this problem to Google Help Community as well](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ZMpE_ovZrvE).  The response from Google Help Community is:

> "I see that you are using Chrome Beta which is an experimental version of Chrome in which new features are tested. I'd recommend to use Chrome Stable which has gotten the full testing and is the updated version. It is the best bet to avoid crashes and other issues."

For now, that should be marked as the correct answer.  I just tested `wss://localhost` on Chrome 59 (Canary/Beta) and it's working.

Note, moving forward, this [functionality is subject for removal due to Chromium issue `#378566`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378566) due to the security implications.  For those of us requiring `wss://` in this fashion, we should receive deprecation warnings prior to removal.  As of Chrome 59 (Canary/Beta), this deprecation is not present.